# "Never Show" missing on some contacts in Gmail chat

Tags: google-talk

Similar to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat, I'm trying to remove some contacts from my Gmail chat list. But for some of my contacts, there is no "More options" pull-down menu containing *Auto*, *Always Show*, *Never Show* and *Block*.

What gives?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Those are contacts to whom you might have sent a chat invitation but they never accepted. (Or have accepted and removed you from their chat list afterwards — although I’m not 100% sure about this possibility.) To remove them from that list, you have to delete them from your contacts list. (But they will reappear if you add them back to your contacts, *with the exact email address*.)