# GMail chat list doesn't show the "More options" or "Caret" icon

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-talk

I was trying to organize my Gmail chat contact list, I remember that previously there was a "More options" button and then it was replaced by a "Caret" icon which open a dropdown menu with the option for show/hide the contact.  (Auto, Always show, Never show etc.)

What I have noticed now is that I don't have the "Caret" icon anymore, not sure what happened here.

This an image of how the overlay window for any of my contacts is shown now.

I am using Ubuntu-14.04.01 LTS + Firefox-34.0 or Chrome-39 and Hangouts as the chat app.

[image]

This question is very similar to: ["Never Show" missing on some contacts in Gmail chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66787/never-show-missing-on-some-contacts-in-gmail-chat) but the OP in that question never replied or added more information.

Comment: Check whether this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/6XN3PHBq6FQ helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Vembu, that seems to be the same issue I am having here, but not a complete solution yet, I want to keep those people in my contacts, I just don't want them to show in my list of contacts for chat.

Comment: I have the same issue. The missing down arrow appears for contacts who have gmail accounts and don't. One observation is that the contacts that don't have the down arrow are ones that I've merged because they have or had multiple email addresses.

Comment: Are you using the old chat or Hangouts?

Comment: My UI says "Hangouts Contacts"/"Hangouts Conversations" at the bottom of the left sidebar in GMail. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is using Hangouts instead of Google Chat as the chat app in Gmail, the caret / more options aren't displayed in the pop up contact card. It is t in the contact list view on the side panel. Move your mouse over someone's name and click the drop-down menu icon [image: drop-down menu icon] that appears. You can also right-click on the person's name to make the drop-down menu to appear.

**References**
[See people’s online status - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111918?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works as expected, the dropdown menu contains a "Hide xxxxx" option.

Comment: When I hover the mouse over a contact name, the pop up contact card appears, not a drop-down menu icon. Is there another side panel contact list than the chat ?

Comment: @philfr The Hangouts side panel has two tabs, one for un-archived conversations, the other for contacts.

Comment: @Rubén : OK, looks like this is different for google apps accounts. I just tried with a standard google account and I can see these tabs. But not on my google apps account, where I cannot hide some contacts while I can hide other ones. Very strange and annoying.

Comment: @philfr I have  Google Apps for Work, for Education and consumer accounts and all of them that have enabled Hangouts as the Gmail chat app, looks the same. Consider to post a new question including snapshots of what you see in both accounts.

Comment: @Rubén I went to the google apps domain administration page, and forced the use of hangouts (it was on chat hangouts or google talk). Now I have the hangouts sidebar in gmail, with the tabs. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. This still doesn't explain the behaviour of google talk, however.